# How to format and truncate numbers when converting XML to XLS (using XSL)

Tags: xml, xslt, number-formatting, xls

I am converting an XML to Excel XLS with XSL. 
How can I format the number to be 3 decimal, and truncate ? 
So, if the number in XML is 101.746789, I want the number in Excel to be 101.746.

When I use the below XSL,the number in Excel becomes 101.747.

```html
<td style='mso-number-format:"\#\,\#\#0\.000";'>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Price"/>
</td>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate how much of the number you need to keep using `substring-before()` and then do the actual truncating with `substring()`...

```
<xsl:variable name="length" 
            select="string-length(substring-before(normalize-space(Price),'.'))+4"/>
<td style="mso-number-format: '\#\,\#\#0\.000';">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(Price),1,$length)"/>
</td>
```

You should end up with something like:

```
<td style="mso-number-format: '\#\,\#\#0\.000';">101.746</td>
```

If you wanted to do the actual formatting with XSLT, you could use `format-number()`...

```
format-number(substring(normalize-space(Price),1,$length),',##0.###')
```